# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: node.js, promise, cheerio

I'm here doing a scraper using node.js request and request-promise, cheerio.

My code:

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const rp = require("request-promise");

const url = "https://singapore.craigslist.org/d/automotive-services/search/aos"

const scrapeResults = [];

async function scrapeJobHeader() {

    try {

        const htmResult = await rp.get(url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
        $(".result-info").each((index, element) => {

        const resultTitle = $(element).children(".result-title");
        title = resultTitle.text();
        link = resultTitle.attr("href");
        const datePosted = $(element).children("time").attr("datetime");


        const scrapResult = {title, link, datePosted};
        scrapeResults.push(scrapResult);
        return scrapeResults;

        });

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(err);
    }
}

async function scrapeDescription(jobWithHeaders) {

    return await Promise.all(
        jobWithHeaders.map(async job => {

        const htmResult = await rp.get(job.url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
        $(".print-qrcode-container").remove();
        job.description = $("#postingbody").text();

    })
    );

}

async function scrapeCraigslist() {

    const jobWithHeaders = await scrapeJobHeader();
    const jobsFullData = await scrapeDescription();
    console.log(jobFullData);
}
scrapeCraigslist();
```

When I run the code I get error like:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist>node index.js
(node:19808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at scrapeDescription (C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist\index.js:42:24) 
    at scrapeCraigslist (C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist\index.js:62:32)
```

How I can fix this error and what wrong I'm doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this `await scrapeDescription();`, but you can't call that function without passing it an array.

When you do, then your argument `jobWithheaders` is `undefined` and you then try to do `undefined.map()` which gives you the error you see.

It looks like maybe you just need to change this:

```
async function scrapeCraigslist() {

    const jobWithHeaders = await scrapeJobHeader();
    const jobsFullData = await scrapeDescription();
    console.log(jobFullData);
}
```

to this:

```
async function scrapeCraigslist() {

    const jobWithHeaders = await scrapeJobHeader();
    const jobsFullData = await scrapeDescription(jobWithHeaders);   // <===
    console.log(jobFullData);
}
```

---

Also, there's no reason to do:

```
return await Promise.all(...)
```

Change that to:

```
return Promise.all(...)
```

Either way, you're returning a promise that resolves to the same value.  Basically, there's never any reason inside an `async` function to do `return await somePromise`.  Just return the promise directly without the `await`.  All the `await` does (if not optimized out by the interpreter) is wait for the promise to resolve, get value out of it, then take the promise that was already returned from the `async` function and make that value the resolved value of that promise.  Which gives you the identical result as just returning the promise you already had without the `await`.

---

Change this:

```
const scrapeResults = [];

async function scrapeJobHeader() {

    try {

        const htmResult = await rp.get(url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
        $(".result-info").each((index, element) => {

        const resultTitle = $(element).children(".result-title");
        title = resultTitle.text();
        link = resultTitle.attr("href");
        const datePosted = $(element).children("time").attr("datetime");


        const scrapResult = {title, link, datePosted};
        scrapeResults.push(scrapResult);
        return scrapeResults;

        });

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
async function scrapeJobHeader() {
    const scrapeResults = [];
    const htmResult = await rp.get(url);
    const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
    $(".result-info").each((index, element) => {
        const resultTitle = $(element).children(".result-title");
        const title = resultTitle.text();
        const link = resultTitle.attr("href");
        const datePosted = $(element).children("time").attr("datetime");

        const scrapResult = {title, link, datePosted};
        scrapeResults.push(scrapResult);
    });
    return scrapeResults;
}
```

And, then change this:

```
scrapeCraigslist();
```

to this:

```
scrapeCraigslist().then(results => {
    // use the results in here only
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Then, change this:

```
async function scrapeDescription(jobWithHeaders) {

    return await Promise.all(
        jobWithHeaders.map(async job => {

        const htmResult = await rp.get(job.url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
        $(".print-qrcode-container").remove();
        job.description = $("#postingbody").text();

    })
    );

}
```

to this:

```
function scrapeDescription(jobWithHeaders) {

    return Promise.all(
        jobWithHeaders.map(async job => {
            const htmResult = await rp.get(job.url);
            const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
            $(".print-qrcode-container").remove();
            job.description = $("#postingbody").text();
            return job;
        });
    );
}
```

Comment: Updated question with your answer

Comment: @Hamza2020 - DO NOT update your question in that way.  That's not how stackoverflow works as you just ruin the answers that were posted based on your original question and that's a major disservice to both the people trying to help you and the people that read this question/answers later.  Leave your original question the way it was.  If you are still having a promise after incorporating the code from an answer, you can ADD to your question a new set of code with a further description of the remaining problem.  Please revert your question to the original code.

Comment: @Hamza2020 - Further, there is NOT the SAME error after incorporating my answer.  You may have a similar error, but on a different line of code.  Details are important here.  If you have multiple problems in the code, we may have to fix each one at a time.  And, when you have an error, please report the exact error and tell us which line of code the line numbers correspond to.  Details matter.

Comment: I'm really sorry . i just reverted to old. but my problem still remaining the same.

Comment: What is the exact error and line of code for the new error?

Comment: (node:3168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at scrapeDescription (C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist\index.js:42:24)
    at scrapeCraigslist (C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist\index.js:63:32)

Comment: jobWithHeaders.map(async job => {

Comment: @Hamza2020 - Have you done any debugging of this yourself?  Put `console.log()` statements in various places to find out why something is `undefined`.  Seriously, this is basic debugging.  Even better, use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the start of `scrapeDescription` and look at the state to see what's not correct.  You should be able to solve problems yourself using simple debugging techniques.

Comment: @Hamza2020 - And, you do need the `return job` that you added and then removed.

Comment: Yes. i can see that scrapeJobHeader() function return the array as undefined but when i use console.log() to print it works.

Comment: the only problem i think when i use  return scrapeResults; it goes to undefined but when i use console.log(scrapeResults) it prints

Comment: @Hamza2020 - You don't show where you're trying to use `scrapeResults`, but I would guess you're trying to use it BEFORE it's been populated.  I will update my answer with several other problems I can see here.

Comment: @Hamza2020 - I've added a bunch to my answer.  I'm going to sleep now so hopefully you can figure it out from here.